# socket.io server on android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to implement a **socket.io server on Android**.

For some reason, all the tutorial/snippets (for instance [this](https://medium.com/@mrcurious/best-practices-of-socket-io-with-android-9f9cb4eb744e), or [that](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)) I find when searching for "Android Socket.io (server)" are: node server, Android socket.io client. Ie., I wasn't able to identify a single case where you have the socket.io server on the Android.

**Is it possible at all to have a socket.io server running on an Android device?** If yes, **how?**

Comment: Please post some code or what you have done so far?

Comment: Any progress? I am dealing with the same problem!

Comment: @rkarami unfortunately not.